# function will be called to many times

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem with a funtion i called in my html-file.
There my html:

```
        <div>Rolle(n):
          <div *ngFor="let borrowerrole of borrowerroles" class="option-group">
             <label for="{{borrowerrole.id}}" [(ngModel)]="borrower.borrowerRoles"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ngDefaultControl>
             <input type="checkbox" name="{{borrowerrole.id}}" id="{{borrowerrole.id}}"
             [ngValue]="borrowerrole" [checked]="checkedValues(borrower.borrowerRoles, borrowerrole)" (click)="setCheckbox($event, borrowerrole)">{{borrowerrole.name}}
            </label>
           </div>
        </div>
```

And there my Ts:

```
  public checkedValues(borrowerroles, role: BorrowerRole) {
    if (this.borrower.borrowerRoles) {
      let match: boolean = false;
      borrowerroles.forEach(borrowerrole => {
        if (borrowerrole.name == role.name) {
          match = true;
          this.newBorrowerRoles.push(role);
        }
      });
      return match
    }
  }
```

Problem: my funtion CheckedValue will be called to may times and I know (i think) it's because of this call borrower.borrowerRoles in my funtion. do someone konw how i can fix it?!

Comment: Store the value returned by `checkedValues(...)` in a member variable and use that on the template?

Comment: i'm using this to check if name(s) are already used in my checkbox and if yes then i set this to yes.

Comment: @herbigjson you are using a "get x" function to cause a side effect by pushing something into an array. That's really bad practice.

Comment: Everytime you do modify a `binded data` that modify the HTML, Angular - by default - will check everything. You basically are in an infinite loop. As Poul said, it's a bad practise. you should change the logic and check for `checked` before passing the data to the `ngFor`. Also have a look at `ChangeDetectionStrategy`, it would help you out as well.